# How to differentiate dialog user close action vs code close action

Tags: java, dialog

Here's my scenario:
When user clicks on an add button, i will open a dialog showing adding in progress, and when the add process is done, the code will close the dialog. But when it's in progress and the user clicks on the cross button on top to close the dialog, i want to fire an event.

Question:
How do write a code that allows me to capture the dialog close event that's being triggered by a user closing the dialog?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: can't you use `setNegativeButton()` of the dialog